# Restoring terminal/TTY to normal after virt-install?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, virsh, virt-install

After having created a VM with `virt-install` then the terminal is only 24 lines, where the terminal have 70 lines.

I recall seeing a similar issue with `virsh console`.

## Question

Ideally would I like both `virt-install` and `virsh console` use the entire terminal, but a way to restore the terminal back to normal after use, would be much apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `reset` command. Its purpose is to reset the terminal to a sane state after it has gone haywire.

The man page explains the specifics of how it reconfigures a terminal, if you need to get down into those weeds.